# Parse error near `&' while setting Heroku config vars

Tags: heroku, zsh

I am setting my Heroku config variable through terminal, and get this error:

> zsh: parse error near `&'

my zsh version is 5.7.1 platform: Mac Mojave

Here is the command I'm running:

```
heroku config:set vidly_db=mongodb://vidlyuser:mypassword@vidly-shard-00-00-yyjmw.mongodb.net:27017,vidly-shard-00-01-yyjmw.mongodb.net:27017,vidly-shard-00-02-yyjmw.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=vidly-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`&` is a special character in Zsh (and Bash, and most other Unixy shells)¹. Wrap your value in quotes:

```
heroku config:set vidly_db='mongodb://vidlyuser:mypassword@vidly-shard-00-00-yyjmw.mongodb.net:27017,vidly-shard-00-01-yyjmw.mongodb.net:27017,vidly-shard-00-02-yyjmw.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=vidly-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true'
```

---

¹For example, [it's used for backgrounding jobs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Jobs-_0026-Signals.html).

Comment: Single quotes was the answer. Using double quotes fails.