# Terminal throwing error around ampersand (&) on curl request

Tags: curl, terminal, zsh

I am trying to do a pretty simple curl request to a public API using Terminal on a Mac running Big Sur and zsh as my shell. Here's the command:

```
https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2021-11-11&end_date=2021-11-11&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
zsh: parse error near `&'
```

I don't understand what it means as there are no quotes in the command. I tried wrapping the key in quotes to see if that would resolve it, same message, then tried wrapping the dates and keys, same thing, switched the order of the arguments, same.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: ZSH will try to parse those `&`, `=` etc. YOu';ll need to escape them: `curl https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed\?start_date\=2021-11-11\&end_date\=2021-11-11\&api_key\=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` (Or use quotes...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse error near \`&' while setting Heroku config vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802157/parse-error-near-while-setting-heroku-config-vars)

Comment: Better yet, just (single) quote the entire URL. You don't *intend* the shell to process it, regardless of its contents, so don't give it a chance. Then you don't have to pick through the URL and decide which characters need to be escaped and which don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote the *"offending"* argument, since it contains shell
metacharacters

curl
https://www.google.com/search?q=test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

should become

curl "
[https://www.google.com/search?q=test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab"](https://www.google.com/search?q=test&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab%22)

You can use single or double quotes, or you can escape (prefixing with a
blackslash) only the & and the ? character, since they both are shell
metacharacters, like this:

curl
[https://www.google.com/search\?q=test\&ie=utf-8\&oe=utf-8\&client=firefox-b-ab](https://www.google.com/search%5C?q=test%5C&ie=utf-8%5C&oe=utf-8%5C&client=firefox-b-ab)

You can read more about shell metacharacters here:

http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/unix_sg/shell/metachar.html

I hope to have been helpful, best regards